# I have to enter inputs (a) and (b) from the keyboard. And I have to create an array of size b. And print the result of nested loops from code c

Tags: arrays, assembly, mips

I have to enter inputs (a) and (b) from the keyboard. And I have to create an array of size b. And print the result of nested loops for verification
the loop contain this code..

```
.text
.main
addi $t0, $zero, -1         #i = -1

for1loop:
addi $t0, $t0, 1            #i += 1
slt $t2, $t0, $s0           #i < a
beq $t2, $zero, exit        #if $t2 == 0, go to exit
and $t1, $t1, $zero         #j = 0

for2loop: slt $t2, $t1, $s1 #j < b
beq $t2, $zero, for1loop    #if $t2 == 0, branch to for1tst         
sll $t4, $t1, 4             #reg $t4 = 4 * j
add $t2, $t0, $t4           #reg $t2 = i + 4 * j
add $t3, $s2, $t1           #reg $t3 = &D[j]
sw $t2, 0($t3)              #store $s2 in address pointed by $t3
addi $t1, $t1, 1            #j += 1
j for2loop                  #jump to for2tst

li $v0,10 # code for exit
syscall # exit program
```

Comment: It's not at all clear what your actual question is, and therefore it is pretty much impossible to provide any meaningful answer. You need to be a lot more specific in explaining your problem.

Comment: As such this is not a homework (but more an error solving) site; you are faster searching for "mips assembler input number" or such. Good luck

Comment: On MARS, there are `syscall`s for reading integers from the user.  http://courses.missouristate.edu/kenvollmar/mars/help/syscallhelp.html